# PHP stdClass how to access variables?

Tags: php

I have function to return a stdClass object. when i do a

```
print_r($obj);
```

i get following as the output.

```
stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => 0744202068 [1] => 0744202069 [2] => 0744202071 [3] => 0744202072 [4] => 0744202073 [5] => 0744202074 [6] => 0744202075 [7] => 0744202076 ) )
```

How do i access these variables as an array or convert these object array to a normal php array ?

Comment: typecast to array like, $myArray = (array) $obj;

Comment: Cast to array or use the object operator `->`. In this case it looks like it's just an array in a object. So you could just say `$obj = $obj->string;` and use `$obj[0 ... 7]`.

Comment: @DaveChen your comment should be an answer.

Comment: This *has* to be a dupe but I can't find it. Anyone?

Comment: @DaveChen Just had to use Google. Popped up instantly. :)